# Angular UI Redirects to API URL

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-http

I am building an application using Asp.Net WebAPI and Angular.

We are implementing Windows Authentication on both the UI application and WebAPI.

While running the application in the browser the first time, the Windows Authentication popup is shown for. But instead of waiting until the user has authenticated, the application redirects to API url in browser.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: make async call to api and wait for its results before showing window auth popup

Comment: Please provide some code on how your authentication logic looks like